# Oracle 11g Deleting large amount of data without generating archive logs

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, delete-row

I need to delete a large amount of data from my database on a regular basis. The process generates huge volume of archive logs. We had a database crash at one point because there was no storage space available on archive destination. How can I avoid generation of logs while I delete data?

The data to be deleted is already marked as inactive in the database.  Application code ignores inactive data. I do not need the ability to rollback the operation.

I cannot partition the data in such a way that inactive data falls in one partition that can be dropped. I have to delete the data with delete statements.

I can ask DBAs to set certain configuration at table level/schema level/tablespace level/server level if needed.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: If you have the enterprise edition, you can use partitioning and then just drop the partition.

Comment: If the data is "marked as inactive" and you have the ability to partition the table (i.e. you have the enterprise edition and the partitioning option), I don't understand why you cannot partition the data such that the inactive data falls in one partition.  Can't you partition on whatever column(s) allow you to mark the data as inactive?  What fraction of the data are you deleting?  It may be more efficient to move the data you want to keep to a separate table, truncate the first table, and then rename the new table.

Comment: Can you alter the table to set NOLOGGING, delete the rows, then turn logging back on?

Comment: @Justin,@a_horse_with_no_name I have a SLICE table which have an "IsActive" column. The SLICE gets inactivated when certain events take place. There is another table SLICE_DATA which has a SLICE_ID. There are multiple rows in SLICE_DATA for each SLiCE_ID. So, I cannot determine which data is inactive in SLICE_DATA without looking at SLICE. That is the reason I cannot partition SLICE_DATA in a way that all inactive data falls in one partition.

Comment: @Brad That seems like a good idea. But I read in some places that DELETE statement will still create archive logs. Please let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @Sameer - I'm still not clear on why you cannot use reference partitioning on the child table http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#CACIHDII

Comment: @Justin Thanks for the link about reference partitioning. What happens when I mark a slice inactive? Does that data move from one partition to another? It would be a huge data movement. Would it block the update statement that marks slice inactive? Would it also generate archive logs when this movement happens?

Comment: @Sameer - That would depend on how the parent was partitioned and whether inactivating a parent row changed the partition that the parent row would be in.  If the update to the parent would change the parent row's partition then it would necessarily change the child row's partition which would involve redo generation.

Comment: @Brad finally we went with nologging solution and it worked fine. Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @Brad Did you post an answer? I don't see your answer.

Comment: @Sameer, one of the mods deleted it, but I undeleted it.  You should be able to accept it now.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Alter the table to set NOLOGGING, delete the rows, then turn logging back on.

Answer (score 2):

What proportion of the data on the table would be deleted, what volume? Are there any referential integrity constraints to manage or is this table childless?

Depending on the answers , you might consider:

1. "CREATE TABLE keep_data UNRECOVERABLE AS SELECT * FROM ... WHERE
   [keep condition]"
2. Then drop the original table
3. Then rename keep_table to original table
4. Rebuild the indexes (again with unrecoverable to prevent redo),constraints etc.

The problem with this approach is it's a  multi-step DDL, process, which you will have a job to make fault tolerant and reversible.

A safer option might be to use data-pump to:

1. Data-pump expdp to extract the "Keep" data
2. TRUNCATE the table
3. Data-pump impdp import of data from step 1, with direct-path

At this point I suggest you read the Oracle manual on Data Pump, particularly the section on Direct Path Loads to be sure this will work for you.

MY preferred option would be partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the best way would be TenG solution (CTAS, drop and rename table) but it seems it's impossible for you.
Your only problem is the amount of archive logs and database crash problem. In this case, maybe you could partition your delete statement (for example per 10.000 rows).
Something like:

```
declare 
e number;
i number
begin
  select count(*) from myTable where [delete condition];
  f :=trunc(e/10000)+1;
  for i in 1.. f
  loop
    delete from myTable where [delete condition] and rownum<=10000;
    commit;
    dbms_lock.sleep(600); -- purge old archive if it's possible
  end loop;
end;
```

After this operation, you should reorganize your table which is surely fragmented.